# Check custom object's value inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I have a class A.

```
 static class A {
  /** true if any null value is seen in the input, null values are to be ignored */
  boolean isNull = false;
}
```

I initiate multiple objects of Class A, then try iterate over it to know whether all of the objects have isNull=true in for loop.

```
public A mergeAs(Iterable<A> Aobjects) {

  for (A a : Aobjects) {
    //check if all a.isNull=true
   }
}
```

I need help with writing the logic.

Comment: I'm confused about what the problem is. You don't know how to check if a boolean is true or false?

Comment: I actually want to check isNull for all initiated objects. @Amongalen

Comment: And what `A` objectis supposed to be returned from `mergeAs` function? Or it needs to be `boolean`?

Comment: `return StreamSupport.stream(Aobjects.spliterator(), false).allMatch(a -> a.isNull);`

Comment: Then just iterate over them, return false if any of them is false or true if all are true.

Comment: mergeAs would return A objects. If all of all the values of initiated As objects are true, then mergeA object would have isNull true.  @AlexRudenko

Answer (score 0):

Logic can be altered, but with the same behavior.

Basically, a list is needed to store all object and a custom method to retrieve specific objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CheckObj {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyList lst = new CheckObj().new MyList();
        lst.add(new CheckObj().new A(true));
        lst.add(new CheckObj().new A(false));
        lst.add(new CheckObj().new A(false));
        lst.add(new CheckObj().new A(true));
        lst.getNotNull().forEach(System.out::println);
        lst.forEach(System.out::println);;
    }
    class A{
        boolean isNull = false;
        A(boolean flag)
        {
            isNull = flag;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return this.hashCode()+",flag="+isNull;
        }
    }
    class MyList extends ArrayList<A>
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public List<A> getNotNull()
        {
            List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
            for(A obj:this)
            {
                if(obj.isNull == false)
                {
                    list.add(obj);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
specific objects
713338599,flag=false
168423058,flag=false

all objects
1160460865,flag=true
713338599,flag=false
168423058,flag=false
1247233941,flag=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that class `A` has appropriate getter and constructor with a parameter to set `isNull` field:

```java
static class A {
  /** true if any null value is seen in the input, null values are to be ignored */  
    boolean isNull = false;

    public A(boolean isNull) {
        this.isNull = isNull;
    }

    public boolean isNull() {
        return this.isNull;
    }
}
```

Method `mergeAs` may be implemented as:

```java
public A mergeAs(Iterable<A> Aobjects) {
    return new A(
        StreamSupport.stream(Aobjects.spliterator(), false).allMatch(A::isNull)
    );
}
```